# What happens if election fraud is found after a president is elected?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, law, election-fraud

A proportion of Donald Trump's supporters believe that the presidential election that has recently led to Joe Biden being sworn in was fraudulent. As I recall, numerous states, such as Arizona, are currently under pressure to audit their elections. Suppose that one such audit happens and finds very strong evidence of fraud that happened in favor of Joe Biden. What happens then? Has this ever happened before? If not, what do the laws say?

Note: The key part of this question is how the finding of fraud would affect a president that has already entered office.

Comment: Not using my close vote here because it would singlehandedly close your q, but most of what you ask has been answered before https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/60732/was-there-ever-an-election-in-the-us-that-was-overturned-by-the-courts-due-to-fr and the rest didn't happen.

Comment: Is mentioning specific parties useful here?  This Q. reads like more promotional [Sea Lioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_lioning) of Trump's baseless claims.

Comment: I asked a question before that addresses one part of your question: [What would happen if vote tallies were discovered to be changed?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16551/what-would-happen-if-vote-tallies-were-discovered-to-be-changed).

Comment: @Fizz "most of what you ask has been answered before" so why not use your singlehandedly vote power? :)

Comment: An AP audit of FL in early 2001 found that under the potential recount standards considered, Gore would have won if the process played out. Nobody did anything because that ship had sailed. No election is perfect, but a time comes where it's too late (Dec 14th in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if election fraud is found after a president is elected?

There is nothing in the Constitution, or the laws of the United States, that would allow overturning a presidential election, after the House (and Senate) have completed their obligations under the Constitution ([Twelfth Amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/amdt12-1/ALDE_00000990/)) and the [Electoral Count Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/15).

No presidential election has ever been overturned.

Any fraud, whenever it may have occurred or found to have occurred in the selection of electors for the president and vice president (or election of Senators or Representatives), may be punished as a Federal Crime.

Crimes related to elections are defined in [18 U.S. Code CHAPTER 29—ELECTIONS AND POLITICAL ACTIVITIES](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-29) § 592 - 611.